# Interval of hours or days to send proactive message in messenger

Tags: botframework, broadcast, facebook-messenger, messenger, proactive

What is the range of hours or days that I can send a proactive message to facebook messenger users through botframework?

NodeJS SDK - botbuilder version 3.14

I'm using code sample below

```
// send simple notification
function sendProactiveMessage(address) {
  var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
  msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
  msg.textLocale('en-US');
  bot.send(msg);
}

var savedAddress;
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// Do GET this endpoint to delivey a notification
server.get('/api/CustomWebApi', (req, res, next) => {
    sendProactiveMessage(savedAddress);
    res.send('triggered');
    next();
  }
);

// root dialog
bot.dialog('/', function(session, args) {

  savedAddress = session.message.address;

  var message = 'Hello! In a few seconds I\'ll send you a message proactively to demonstrate how bots can initiate messages.';
  session.send(message);

  message = 'You can also make me send a message by accessing: ';
  message += 'http://localhost:' + server.address().port + '/api/CustomWebApi';
  session.send(message);

  setTimeout(() => {
   sendProactiveMessage(savedAddress);
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? The maximum time between 2 messages? It's not clear, sorry

Comment: Yes, The maximum time between 2 messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting Facebook Messenger Policy:

> 24-Hour Messaging Window
>
> Businesses and developers using the Send API
>   have up to 24 hours to respond to a message sent by a person in
>   Messenger when using standard messaging. A bot may also send one
>   additional message after the 24-hour time limit has expired. The
>   24-hour limit is refreshed each time a person responds to a business
>   through one of the eligible actions listed in Messenger Conversation
>   Entry Points. This is commonly referred to as the '24 + 1 policy'.
>
> For information on how you may be able to send messages outside the
>   24-hour messaging window, see the Tags documentation, and Sponsored
>   Messages.

This policy is available here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview#standard_messaging

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas R